# Retornar varios valores desde una función en C

Tags: c, funcion

Estaba pensando en cómo retornar varios valores desde una función en C. Se me ha ocurrido emplear una estructura que almacene todos los valores que quiero retornar. Pongo el siguiente ejemplo que funciona correctamente y cumple lo que estoy buscando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Declaración de la estructura
struct estructura {
   int num1;
   int num2;
};


// Función que permite retornar más de 1 variable
struct estructura funcion ( void )
{
    struct estructura estructura_en_funcion;

    printf(" -- DATOS DENTRO DE FUNCION --\n");
    printf("Numero 1: ");
    scanf ("%d", &estructura_en_funcion.num1);
    printf("Numero 2: ");
    scanf ("%d", &estructura_en_funcion.num2);

    return estructura_en_funcion;
}


int main() {

    struct estructura datos;      // Creación de estructura

    datos = funcion();            // Asignamos los valores de la estructura creada con el retorno de los valores de la función

    // Expresar datos obtenidos mediante el retorno múltiple de la función
    printf(" -- DATOS DENTRO DE MAIN --\n");
    printf("Numero 1: %d\n", datos.num1);
    printf("Numero 2: %d", datos.num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Mi pregunta es si hay algún modo más elegante para que la función retorne más de una variable (incluso de distinto tipo). Algo parecido a lo que se puede conseguir fácilmente con `Matlab` mediante las instrucciones `[num1, num2] = funcion()`.

También había pensado en crear un array con las variables y que la función retorne un puntero a dicho array y poder así leer los datos, pero no sé si es más eficiente la solución que planteo, otra que sea posible realizar, o la del puntero al array.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi pregunta es si hay algún modo más elegante para que la función retorne más de una variable

Actualmente, solo hay dos formas de devolver múltiples valores:

- Retornando una estructura: es el mecanismo que comentas en la pregunta
- Mediante punteros en los parámetros de la función:

  ```
    void func(int input1, float input2, double* output1, char* output2);
  ```

En principio no hay una solución que sea mejor que la otra en general. Cada una tiene sus propias ventajas e inconvenientes. Así, por enumerar algunas:

- Retorno de estructura:

  | Ventajas | Inconvenientes |
  | --- | --- |
  | No es necesario cambiar la firma de la función al añadir o quitar parámetros (menos recompilaciones e interfaz más estable) | Tienes que mantener la estructura |
  | La firma de la función es más simple |  |
  | Es más complicado usar mal la función |  |
- Uso de punteros:

  | Ventajas | Inconvenientes |
  | --- | --- |
  | Se recuperan solos los valores que te interesan en cada momento | Gestión de punteros |
  |  | Cada vez que es necesario añadir, quitar o modificar un tipo de salida es necesario modificar la firma de la función |

> Algo parecido a lo que se puede conseguir fácilmente con Matlab mediante las instrucciones

Esa solución no es más que un azucarillo sintáctico de Matlab. Lo que hace Matlab por detrás es justamente crear una estructura de datos donde empaquetar todos los valores a retornar.

C no dispone de esas capacidades. El compilador hace menos magia al respecto (de hecho no hace ninguna magia) y eso te obliga a ser más explícito en cuanto a tus intenciones.

> También había pensado en crear un array con las variables y que la función retorne un puntero a dicho array y poder así leer los datos

Esta solución tiene una limitación importante, y es que todos los valores deben ser del mismo tipo. C no admite un array de tipos heterogéneos

Comment: Gracias por la información @eferion, simplemente estaba tratando de ver si existía alguna posibilidad alternativa que fuese mejor a la que implantaba con las estructuras. Muchas gracias de nuevo, muy bien explicado.